# C# Receive certain object from recursive ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<ParameterNodeEntity>`.

ParameterNodeEntity is a custom class:

```
public class ParameterNodeEntity
{
    public ParameterNodeEntity()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<ParameterNodeEntity>();
        Parameters = new ObservableCollection<ParameterEntity>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ParameterNodeEntity> Nodes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ParameterEntity> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it can contain both items from its own type (`ParameterNodeEntity`) and Parameters (`ParameterEntity`), as well as having a name and a path.

The `ParameterEntity` looks like this:

```
public abstract class ParameterEntity
{
    public ParameterEntity(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Both classes have a `Path` property.

As an example:

```
Node1
- Node2
  - Node3
    - Parameter1
    - Parameter2
    - Node4
      - Node5
```

`Node 4` would have the path `Node1.Node2.Node3.Node4`. `Parameter1` would have the path `Node1.Node2.Node3.(Parameter)Parameter1`.

What I'm trying to do is to remove a specific item by its path. I tried the following:

```
    public void DeleteParameterNode(ObservableCollection<ParameterNodeEntity> collection, string path)
    {
        collection.Remove(collection.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Path == path));
    }
```

This works for the item at the highest level, but not for the others.

I appreciate any help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any code to navigate to a given node from the top level given an arbitrarily deep path. There is no way for `ObservableCollection` (or any other piece of code) to know what `"Node1.Node2.Node3"` even means.

It's no wonder it works for the top level but not the others. In your top-level collection, there is an object pathed `"Node1"`, but the object pathed `"Node1.Node2"` is actually in the `"Node1".Nodes` collection, not the top level one.

You have to add code to parse your path and navigate the object tree (possibly recursively) in order to remove the right item from the right collection.

Comment: That clears it up. I hoped for a simple way to extract that object, but I guess I have no choice but to do it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ObservableCollection` does not have any possibility to find a specific object inside a multi-level collection.

Using this approach will deliver the desired object:

```
private ParameterNodeEntity _searchNodeResult;

public void SearchByPath(ParameterNodeEntity nodeEntity, string path)
{
    bool found = false;
    if (nodeEntity.Path != path)
    {
        foreach (ParameterNodeEntity subNode in nodeEntity.Nodes)
        {
            if (!found)
            {
                SearchByPath(subNode, path);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _searchNodeResult = nodeEntity;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

`SearchByPath` requires two parameters: First, the top-level object and second, the parameter to find the desired object.

This is not a very beautiful approach, but in my case it works because the searched-for item definitely exists in all cases.

`_searchNodeResult` will hold the found object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
    public void DeleteParameterNode(ObservableCollection<ParameterNodeEntity> collection, string path)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection.Where(i => i.Path == path))
        {
            collection.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won't work either. `item` returns null in this scenario, although the item with the correct path exists.

Comment: @Kohnarik, maybe to change the code above to match pattern, like collection.Where(i => i.Path.Contains(path))? For example, you will be able to select all the nodes which path contains "Node1.Node2"

Comment: This by itself is not going to work. OP needs to actually parse the string and navigate to the correct collection.